# iOS - embedded view controller prevent update of root view controller UI elements?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I have an embedded storyboard-built view controller in another (main) view controller. In the main view controller I do some processing and show the process parameters by UI-elements in the main view controller. The update of the UI-elements run on the main thread and processing in background, so when I call the processing method from the main VC everything is working fine.

The problems occur when I call the method from the embedded VC - for some reason the UI-elements will not be updated!? When I set a break point in the method it is called and NSLog gives correct output, but no update of the UI-elements happen.

My assumption is that the hierarchy of the controllers prevent that the main VC is updated!? To prove this I added a log inside the processing method to find who is top VC:

```
NSArray *VC=[[self navigationController] viewControllers];
NSLog(@"TopVC: %@", VC.lastObject);
```

From a call the method from the MainVC (is updating elements fine) I get:

```
TopVC: <MainViewController: 0x1003067d0>
```

when I call the same method from embedded VC (is not updating elements) I get:

```
TopVC: (null)
```

Is there a way to set the "focus" back to the main VC to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The main view controller is the embedded view controller's `parentViewController`. Knowing that, you can communicate from the embedded view controller to the main view controller.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to solve this so I decided to rework the setup and removed the embedded view controller and added the controls to the mainviewcontroller - now everything works as expected!